# Creating Adjacency Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, graph

I'm new to Python. I want to create an adjacency list from a dictionary like this format:

```py
{node: {vertex: weight } }
```

but I got stuck in getting this format outputs for a larger graph that has a duplicate key with different values.
I can get this format by list but I wanna do it with a dictionary that accepts multiple same keys as one with different values.

These are my edges between nodes:

```
( 0 , 1 )
( 1 , 2 )
( 2 , 4 )
( 2 , 6 )
( 2 , 3 )
( 0 , 3 )
( 4 , 5 )
( 5 , 6 )
( 4 , 6 )
```

My desired output format is like this below:

```
{0: {1: w01 , 3: w03}, 1: {2: w12 } , ...}
```

But the result of using a dictionary is like below:

```
{0: {1: w01}, 1: {2: w12 } , ...}
```

I can get these two formats with `setdefault` but it's the list:

```
{0: [1, 3], 1: [2], 2: [4, 6, 3], 4: [5, 6], 5: [6]}\
{0: [{1: w01}, {3: w03}], 1: [{2: w02}], ...}
```

Please guide me!

Comment: A "dictionary that accepts multiple same keys" doesn't exist in Python (or elsewhere afaik). Typically you would store a list as the value for a given key.

Comment: Please see [ask] - "please guide me" is not a question we can answer here. We can only help you with code that we can actually see. That said - did you *read the documentation* for `setdefault`? It seems like the problem is that you use `setdefault` to create a `list` by default, and then end up with a `dict` containing `list` values, when you want a `dict` containing `dict` values. Maybe you should use `setdefault` to create some other thing for the default values?

Comment: "My desire output format is like this below" That is not "a dictionary that accepts multiple same keys"; it is simply a dictionary that stores dictionaries as values.